# Why is my background image not showing up

Tags: html, css

I've decided to make a site about the current election(s) and I'm already having trouble with the intro page.

```css
#wrapper {
  height: 900px;
  width:  900px;
  border: solid;black;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
#repicon {
  background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/Ow7TR.png);
  background-size: 140px 140px;
}
```

```html
<div id="Wrapper">
  <div id="repicon"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<div id="Wrapper">
<div id="repicon">sdsdfsdsds</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#wrapper {
    height: 900px;
    width:  900px;
    border: solid;black;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

#repicon {
background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/Ow7TR.png);
//background-size: 140px 140px;
height: 500px;
width: 500px;
}
```

[DEMO LINK](https://jsfiddle.net/f1w9snfb/)

Comment: how would I make this image be at the center?  margin right?

Comment: try add css for image .

Comment: @BlueHorse see my answer for image centered

Answer (score 2):

you have a few typos(`id="Wrapper"` won't match the `#wrapper` in CSS) plus for a `background-image` to work it needs `height`

As your comment, you want the `background-image` centered, just apply `center` in `background` shorthand.

```css
#wrapper {
  height: 900px;
  width: 900px;
  border: solid  black;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
#repicon {
  background: url(http://i.imgur.com/Ow7TR.png) no-repeat center  / 140px 140px;
  height:140px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="repicon"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Its not working because your `div` has no content and that results that it has no `height`. To see your image you have to add content to the div or a `min-height`

```
#repicon {
min-height: 140px;
background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/Ow7TR.png);
background-size: 140px 140px;
}
```

See this working [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jxb5nhyn/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to have content inside your div if you want the "background-image" to show up.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define height and width for #repicon

```css
#wrapper {
  height: 900px;
  width:  900px;
  border: solid;black;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
#repicon {
  background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/Ow7TR.png);
  background-size: 140px 140px;
  width: 140px;
  height: 140px;
}
```

```html
<DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <title>2016 Election</title>
      <meta name="keywords" content="Donald Trump, Bernie Sanders, Ted Cruz, Hillary Clinton, 2016 Elections, 2016 Primaries, Republican, Democrat"> 
      <meta name="description" content="2016 Presidential Election, Primary Nominations">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
      <div id="Wrapper">
        <div id="repicon"></div>
      </div>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Just add "&nbsp" to your div and update your css for best result.

```css
#wrapper {
 height: 900px;
 width:  900px;
 border: solid;black;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

#repicon {
background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/Ow7TR.png);
background-size: 140px 140px;
}
```

```html
<DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>2016 Election</title>
 <meta name="keywords" content="Donald Trump, Bernie Sanders, Ted Cruz, Hillary Clinton, 2016 Elections, 2016 Primaries, Republican, Democrat"> 
 <meta name="description" content="2016 Presidential Election, Primary Nominations">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="Wrapper">
<div id="repicon">&nbsp</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```